# FATA[0015] Error response from daemon: </html> Docker login error

Tags: docker, authentication

I'm able to run all docker commands and able to login to dockerhub on the web. But when I try to login through command prompt I get this

```
sarvagya@CarpeNoctem:~$ sudo docker login
[sudo] password for sarvagya: 
Username: sarvagya3943
Password: 
Email: sarvagyaagarwal01@gmail.com
FATA[0015] Error response from daemon: </html>
```

Cant find anything on the internet regarding this empty error. Can someone please help ?

Comment: Is docker running on a Linux machine or on windows?

Comment: @KapilKhandelwal Linux machine. Ubuntu.

Comment: can you try once restarting docker and then logging in.

Comment: how do i restart ? 
sarvagya@CarpeNoctem:~$ service docker restart
stop: Unknown job: docker
start: Unknown job: docker